# URLs being produced correctly but not directing to correct template

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to follow the [Simple Blog tutorial at Django By Example](http://lightbird.net/dbe/blog.html). I've managed to get as far as producing a site that loads correctly, but while the index view is loading find, and the links to the individual posts show up and appear to be formatted correctly, they point back to the index template so all that happens when you click on them is that it reloads the index view. I'm new to Django and the tutorial is sparse to say the least and not helped by the fact it's written for an old version of Django and I'm using 1.5. I've been staring at it all afternoon and I'm pretty lost.

Here's my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from blog import views

urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
#index
   (r"$", 'main'),
   #ex: /1/
   (r"^(\d+)/$", 'post'),
   #ex: /add_comment/1/
   (r"^add_comment/(\d+)/$", 'add_comment'),
)
```

my views.py

```
from blog.models import Post, PostAdmin, Comment, CommentAdmin

class CommentForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Comment
    exclude = ["post"]

def main (request):
"""Main Listing."""
posts = Post.objects.all().order_by("-created")
paginator = Paginator(posts, 10)

try: page = int(request.GET.get("page", '1'))
except ValueError: page = 1

try:
    posts = paginator.page(page)
except (InvalidPage, EmptyPage):
    posts = patinator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return render_to_response("blog/list.html", dict(posts=posts, user=request.user))


def post (request, pk):
"""single post with comments and comment form"""
post = Post.objects.get(pk=int(pk))
comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=post)
d = dict(post=post, comments=comments, form=CommentForm(), user=request.user)
d.update(csrf(request))
return render_to_response("blog/post.html", d)
```

and the list.html that contains the links that aren't going anywhere!

```
{% extends "blog/bbase.html" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="main">

    <!-- Posts  -->
    <ul>
        {% for post in posts.object_list %}
            <div class="title">{{ post.title }}</div>
            <ul>
                <div class="time">{{ post.created }}</div>
                <div class="body">{{ post.body|linebreaks }}</div>
                <div class="commentlink"><a href="{% url 'blog.views.post' post.pk %}">Comments</a></div>
            </ul>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <!-- Next/Prev page links  -->
    {% if posts.object_list and posts.paginator.num_pages > 1 %}
    <div class="pagination" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-left: -20px; ">
        <span class="step-links">
            {% if posts.has_previous %}
                <a href= "?page={{ posts.previous_page_number }}">newer entries &lt;&lt; </a>
            {% endif %}

            <span class="current">
                &nbsp;Page {{ posts.number }} of {{ posts.paginator.num_pages }}
            </span>

            {% if posts.has_next %}
                <a href="?page={{ posts.next_page_number }}"> &gt;&gt; older entries</a>
            {% endif %}
        </span>
    </div>
    {% endif %}

</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django URL resolver will return the first URL pattern that matches the incoming request. The regex for your 'main' view `r"$"` will match ANY incoming request since you are only looking for `$` which is an end of string character.

You need to alter your 'main' URL regex to be `r'^$'`.

Alternatively, if you would like a catch-all view, you could move the 'main' view to the bottom of your URLs

Comment: Thanks. I knew it had to be something incredibly obvious.